# bibliometrix (Problem in uploading the data)

Tags: database

I am trying to do bibliometrix analysis of articles using the bibliometrix package. I installed the package and then run the library.However, when I am uploading my data, it is showing this error:

> Error in readFiles("C:/Users/patel/savedrecs.bib") :    could not find
>   function "readFiles".

Also. when I am running library this is the massage I am getting.

> library(bibliometrix)   ### load bibliometrix package
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’:  object
>   ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'

In addition:

> Warning message: package ‘bibliometrix’ was built under R version
>   3.4.4

My question is how to upload data? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the package directly from the github repository:

`install.packages("devtools")`# to install the bibliometrix most recent version from GITHUB

`devtools::install_github("massimoaria/bibliometrix")`

Beware! The github version, usually, is the most recent and not fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, I had to install Rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
Then I did the following installs in RStudio

```
> install.packages("bibliometrix", dependencies=TRUE) 
> library(bibliometrix)

To cite bibliometrix in publications, please use:

Aria, M. & Cuccurullo, C. (2017) bibliometrix: An R-tool for comprehensive science mapping analysis, Journal of Informetrics, 11(4), pp 959-975, Elsevier.
                        

http:\\www.bibliometrix.org

                        
To start with the shiny web-interface, please digit:
biblioshiny()

> biblioshiny()
```

Only then all such prerequisite problems got resolved. Without RTools, all such errors were getting reported.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the rtools, then installed the jsonlite package and lastly, installed the bibliometrix package.
now it's working.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: @Tyler2P: Contributors don't earn the privilege of commenting until they receive a reputation of 50. Regardless, short answers are fine if they actually solve the problem. In fact, they may even be preferred in some cases so that they can be marked as the accepted answer, thus allowing the question to be marked as resolved. The problem with short answers is that they're often incomplete or speculative, in which case they might be better as a comment.